# Compile all projects hotkey

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-2009, hotkeys, registerhotkey

I have two projects in a project group that share same units(mostly all).I use both projects in order to test something I've written.

The problem: When I change a unit that is used by both projects and run the current project,the other one uses the old code in that unit(because its not compiled).

The only possibility I know to compile all projects is via the system menu(Projects->Build all projects).

Currently,when one of the projects is ran(with the delphi debugger),the other project's executable is executed,but not compiled.

How do I compile both projects with a hotkey(like <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F9</kbd> for one project)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> really is convenient.

There isn't a single key sequence to compile all projects in the current project group, but you can get at the menu option by using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>

Answer (score 7):

Install GExperts and assign a hotkey of your choice to the IDE menu item.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know about any hotkey for that, but you can easily add a button to your toolbar that will do this with one click.

Customizing the toolbar can be invoked via the toolbar's context menu. In the *command* page search for the corresponding action in the *project* section and drag it to a convenient place.